# Use HermiT in Python

Tags: python, ontology, reasoner, owlready, hermit

We have an ontology but we need to use the reasoner HermiT to infer the sentiment of a given expression. We have no idea how to use and implement a reasoner in python and we could not find a good explanation on the internet. We found that we can use sync_reasoner() for this, but what does this do exactly? And do we have to call the reasoner manually everytime or does it happen automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to implement the reasoner. The `sync_reasoner()` function already calls HermiT internally and does the reasoning for you.

A reasoner will reclassify individuals and classes for you which means it creates a parent-child hierarchy of classes and individuals. When you load an ontology only explicit parent-child relations are represented. However, when you call the reasoner, the parent-child hierarchy is updated to include inferred relations as well.

An example of this is provided in `Owlready2-0.5/doc/intro.rst`. Before calling `sync_reasoner()` calling `test_pizza.__class__` prints `onto.Pizza`, which is explicit information. However, after calling `sync_reasoner()` calling `test_pizza.__class__` prints `onto.NonVegetarianPizza`, which is the inferred information.

Comment: Hi, does sync_reasoner() function check consistency for an ontology?

Comment: Yes, consistency checking is part of the reasoning process.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am facing difficulties in tracing the output. I have one ontology which contain error because I have put Student and Unit as a disjoint class and as well as equivalent class to see what output hermit gives me. But it shows same output for both correct and incorrect file. Please have a look on this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147628/consistency-checking-using-hermit-reasoner-in-python-for-an-ontology
Thanks in advance.